# Determine KOMA-Script section title font size

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, koma-script

I have a document using `scrbook` as document class. Somewhere during the text I would like certain words to have exactly the same font size as the section titles.

Consulting the documentation, I found out that for class options `headings=big|normal` the section title font size is `Large`, while for `headings=small` it is `large`.

How can I always have the proper font size in case I switch to `headings=small` without manually replacing all local font size declarations? In other words: how can I extract and transfer the current section title font size to some other text?

Comment: `\addtokomafont{section}{\footnotesize}`

Comment: Probably `\usefontofkomafont{section}`.

Comment: @Piet, thank you, that worked! If you like to post your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept.

Comment: You could use `\usesizeofkomafont{section}` if only the font size should be the same as for sections (but not the family, series, shape and all other settings as color etc.)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[headings=small]{scrbook}

\newcommand*\fontsizeofsectionheadings{\usefontofkomafont{section}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{chapter}
I need {\fontsizeofsectionheadings words} as {\fontsizeofsectionheadings big} as the section titles, even if \verb|headings=small|.
\end{document}
```